# Extract all reviews for movie if the movie has atleast one rating as '1'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to NEO4J and trying to extract all the movies and the rating for movies if the movie has atleast 1 review with rating'1'.

```
(m:movie)-[r:HAS_REVIEWS]->(r:review)
```

in the relationship WHERE r.rating is the rating field

Any pointers on how I can extract the data?

Comment: Your query attempts to use the `r` variable for 2 different things (the relationship and the end node), which is an error. Also, because of that, it is not clear where the `rating` property is.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
MATCH(m:movie)-[r:HAS_REVIEWS]->(r:review)
where r.rating>0
RETURN DISTINCT m,r;
```

i will suggest first go through the neo4j cypher queries

https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/

Comment: thankyou Govind, for your input. I am looking to extract all the movie and all review(1-5) details if any movie has a rating of 1

Answer (score 0):

@Govind respond can be what is you're looking for, if you only want the review with a `rating > 1`.

But if you want :

- searching a movie that has a `rating = 1`
- then returns all the review of this movie

This is the query :

```
MATCH (m) WHERE exists((m)-[:HAS_REVIEW {rating:1}]->(:Review))
WITH m 
MATCH (m)-[r:HAS_REVIEW]->(review:Review)
RETURN m, r, review
```

FYI, in the pattern in your question, you have defined twice the varaiable `r` (one as the relationship, and the other as the node Review)

---

Update

```
MATCH (m)-[:HAS_REVIEW]->(r:Review)
WHERE r.rating = 1 AND r.date > XXX
WITH m 
  MATCH (m)-[r:HAS_REVIEW]->(r:Review)
  RETURN m AS movie, size((m)-[:HAS_REVIEW]->(:Review)) AS nbReview, r AS review
```

Comment: Thanks logisima. Thats exactly my requirement.

Comment: Now if I want to also include the date condition for the review say where reviewDate > '2019-10-01' and rating =1 and also include the count of reviews for each movie, how can I do that?

Comment: @logisima can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560218/how-to-create-nodes-and-relationships-from-csv-in-neo4j ?